# How to forward User back to desired protected page after successful login with Spring Security

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security to handle all of the authentication of my web app.  Here's the situation, let's say I have three JSP pages:

1) Login Page
2) Default Home Page (needs authentication)
3) user account page (needs authentication)

The standard flow works just fine:

1) User successfully logs in from Login Page
2) User is taken to default homepage

**Here's the use-case I cannot figure out**

1) User attempts to access their account page (but it is password protected) - works
2) User is redirected to enter their credentials - works
3) User successfully gives credentials - works
4) User is redirected to their account page - DOESN'T WORK (it redirects them to the default homepage)

I'm using a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, but the trouble is, whenever I look to the request to see where they came from it's always from `/j_spring_security_check`.

Is there some simple way of isolating what page they came from?

Here's what's in my applicationContext.xml that pertains to my Spring Security setup:

```
<bean id="successfulLoginService" class="com.service.SuccessfulLoginService">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/listings/add_listing.htm"/>
  </bean>

  <security:http pattern="/**.html" security="none" />
  <security:http pattern="/login/*.htm" security="none" />
  <security:http pattern="/listings/listing.htm" security="none" />
  <security:http pattern="/listings/viewListing.htm" security="none" />
  <security:http pattern="/search/keyword/*.htm" security="none" />

  <security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**.htm" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/**.htm" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login/login.htm" authentication-failure-handler-ref="failedLoginService" authentication-success-handler-ref="successfulLoginService"/>
  </security:http>

  <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
      user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
  </security:authentication-manager>
```

Here's my SuccessfulLoginService.java:

```
@Service("successfulLoginService")
public class SuccessfulLoginService extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
  @Autowired
  UserDao userDao;

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
      throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    Users user = null;
    String username = ((SpringSecurityUser) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    try
    {
      user = userDao.getUserByEmail(username);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new ServletException("Failed to login", e);
    }
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);

    response.sendRedirect("/MyApplication" + determineTargetUrl(request, response));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get saved request from `org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCache`.

Inside of your custom success handler:

```
RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
```

Take a look at default `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` for more details.

Comment: I don't know why I never knew how to do that before.  I've literally been looking for this answer for months, I've just kept putting it on the back-burner when I couldn't figure it out.  Thanks very much for taking the time to answer my question Aleksandr, you're my hero for the week.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [default-target-url](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-form-login-default-target-url)? You can use it for redirecting users to some location after successful login.

Comment: I don't believe so, I just tried plugging it in, but that didn't work.  I'm also using authentication-success-handler-ref and that may be causing some confusion in the code.  I tried hooking up a default-target-url in my authentication-success-handler-ref, but it just always navigates to that URL (even if that's not the one I tried to access in the beginning when I didn't have access)